# Implementing Google Authentication in Next.js 12.2.5 - Console Warnings and Sign-In Issue

Tags: authentication, next.js, google-api

I am trying to implement Google authentication in my Next.js 12.2.5 project. I have set up the necessary files and components, including the **`_app.js`**, **`/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`**, and **`testGoogleAUTH.js`** files. However, I am encountering some issues and warnings that I need help with.

When I click on the sign-in button, the authentication flow does not start as expected. I am also receiving warnings related to **`NEXTAUTH_URL`** and **`NO_SECRET`** in the console.

here is the app file:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, session }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    import("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");
  }, []);

  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

the auth file:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
});
```

the testGoogleAUTH page:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";

const TestGoogleAUTH = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  try {
    if (session) {
      return <div>{session}</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>you're not logged in </h1>
          <button onClick={() => signIn()}>signIn</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export default TestGoogleAUTH;
```

When I click on the sign-in button, I encounter the following steps and warnings:

- [Sign-in Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwwnP.png)
- [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nKO4.png)
- [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw5Xp.png)

I have reviewed my code and environment setup multiple times but haven't been able to identify the root cause of the problem. Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Steps I have taken:

1. Configured the necessary environment variables for the Google client ID, client secret, and JWT secret.
2. Verified that the values for the environment variables are correct.
3. Checked the Next.js documentation and followed the recommended setup for **`GoogleProvider`** and **`SessionProvider`**.
4. Ensured that the necessary dependencies are installed and up to date.

Upon clicking the sign-in button, the Google authentication flow should be initiated, allowing users to sign in with their Google accounts successfully.